# Fix stair railing which has nails on the end

Tags: repair, stairs, railing

It looks like end of my stair railing was attached to the wall with four small nails, and it has come off. I tried pushing it back to the wall, but cannot get it to align to the original position (holes are a little below). I was not able to have it align even after applying the downward pressure on the railing. Can you suggest the best way to fix this?

[image: nails]
[image: other side]
[image: whole railing]
[image: other end]

Comment: I've never seen a bannister held up by staples before :\ Unless you can figure out how the rail is attached to the end-cap - I get the feeling it might be some kind of snap-in fitting - then first get rid of the staples, reassemble, then screw the end-cap to the wall, sink/fill as mentioned by Programmer66. Basically, you're going to have to take the whole thing apart to put it back together again. Pictures of the rail/cap disassembled & other end, how it's attached to the bottom post may help prescribe a better method.

Comment: Not staples. Finish nails. As a former trim carpenter, this is just embarrassing to the profession.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hired a professional to get this fixed. They adjusted the balusters, nailed them, and screwed the end cap to the wall. The screw has made the railing very sturdy now.

[image]

Comment: Has the professional explained why it had occurred?

Comment: It was not installed properly before. It detached when put a lot of effort on it while climbing the stairs. The bottom post is also not very sturdy, but would require significant effort to fix, so that is not fixed right now.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your railing was installed correctly in the first place, and suspect the lower end-post may have tilted slightly, so resulting in such a huge gap on the upper end. As the railing assembly has deformed, it requires quite an effort to correct it, which is a job for professionals. Please call a carpenter to assess the situation, cause of the deformation, and please come back to let us know.

Comment: @r13 looks like the gap was caused by the handrail lifting

Comment: @jsotola Yes, but why?

Comment: @r13 weak attachment at top end ... no attachment to spindles ... now  that i think about it, probably what you said, bottom post moving